# Parsing json to interface in typescript and check if it is ok

Tags: json, typescript, parsing

How I can parse a Json string to nested interface type? and check if it is ok?

I have an example but my model is more complex:

```
export interface User = {
    name: Field;
    surname: Field;
};
export interface Field = { icon: string; text: string; visibility: boolean };
export interface Users = User[]
```

It would be:

```
export type user = {
    name: field;
    surname: field;
};
export type field = { icon: string; text: string; visibility: boolean };
export type users = user[]
```

Or it will be classes. It does not matter.

Here a json example:

```
[
{
"name": { "text": "David", "icon": "icon1.png", "visibility": true },
"surname": { "text": "Smith", "icon": "icon2.png", "visibility": true }
},
{
"name": { "text": "Arthur", "icon": "icon3.png", "visibility": true },
"surname": { "text": "L.", "icon": "icon6.png", "visibility": true }
},
{
"name": { "text": "Anthony", "icon": "icon1.png", "visibility": false },
"surname": { "text": "Isaacson", "icon": "icon2.png", "visibility": true }
},
{
"name": { "text": "Mike", "icon": "icon3.png", "visibility": true },
"surname": { "text": "Jobs", "icon": "icon5.png", "visibility": false }
}
]
```

**Edit:**

here an example why Chithambara's approach is invalid: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBArgzhATlAvFA3gKCjqA7AQwFsIAuKAMwEsIAbAEwG5tc4ZFCTzq6nMBfZqEiUaDVBihUAxgHs85OMERU8Ac0ZRgEAB7BFy1RqgA3KnCoAjKrSqhyl2bNoQCeKIMzDo8JHAm%20iADaALqYmC7AUABWcPJKKupQBolqEgAGQZhYAEScEDnk6FA5MvKFJWV4AIwAdGDqOQA0JWYW1ragFcow0PxNmDlsHMQFRSXaehU5AMpEdgAWzZVyeNNVAEz1jS05bVY2diDdiL0eAgO5%20RXFOZPA0wCCiMAL7Mulq%20urAMzbah99h0jiczv1BsNruM7roHuQcgAZWofKrfeQANn%20gPMB06x3IPT6F2ygyhkhhU3hjzwr3kx12qPhVTqDQBuyBhy63AItAQHgGQ3YZNu92mAEk4AQCNI4msGV8mastqzse1OfitKcieCrqMbhNYdMALJUADWBXZOOBXM1YIFkL10NF8IAUrJLHBVbiQdzedrMCF0uFIrAEIg4AARAjAAjJUN%20CQumYAeQAcvUCOGIAAKWLxQzqACUzFWcRctVosjU2cCkejBCCAAYQrV8rV7oXMKXnBAK1Wa2G6zGgj8Ww6SLUqoWgA)

Answer (score 1):

If your validation needs are complex enough, I would evaluate the usage of something like [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts). It is a library used to automatically generate runtime validations based on metadata in your code.

If your needs are more limited, you can just leverage [UserDefined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

What a type guard does is take an `unknown` (or `any`, there is really no difference inside this kind of function) and tells the compiler that the passed in object *is* compatible with a certain interface.

```js
export interface Field {
  icon: string;
  text: string;
  visibility: boolean;
}

export interface User {
  name: Field;
  surname: Field;
}

function isField(obj: any): obj is Field {
  return (
    obj != null &&
    typeof obj.icon === "string" &&
    typeof obj.text === "string" &&
    typeof obj.visibility === "boolean"
  );
}

function isUser(obj: any): obj is User {
  return obj != null && isField(obj.name) && isField(obj.surname);

  // you can get fancy and write something like
  // return obj != null && ['name', 'surname'].every(fieldName => isField(obj[fieldName]))
}

// alternative isUser implementation, using a 
// prototype. This will give you a compile error is the
// interface is updated, but not this prototype.
const userProto: User = {
  name: null,
  surname: null
};

function isUserDynamic(obj: any): obj is User {
  return obj != null && Object.keys(userProto).every(fieldName => isField(obj[fieldName]));
}

function validateUserArray(obj: any): obj is User[] {
  if (obj == null) {
    // depending upon the desired approach, you can throw an exception and bail out,
    // or simply return false.
    throw new Error("The array cannot be null");
  }
  if (!Array.isArray(obj)) return false;

  obj.forEach((user, i) => {
    if (!isUser(user))
      throw new Error(
        `Error at index ${i}: ${JSON.stringify(user)} is not a valid user.`
      );
  });

  return true;
}

const json = `[
  {
    "name": { "text": "David", "icon": "icon1.png", "visibility": true },
    "surname": { "text": "Smith", "icon": "icon2.png", "visibility": true }
  },
  {
    "name": { "text": "Arthur", "icon": "icon3.png", "visibility": true },
    "surname": { "text": "L.", "icon": "icon6.png", "visibility": true }
  },
  {
    "name": { "text": "Anthony", "icon": "icon1.png", "visibility": false },
    "surname": { "text": "Isaacson", "icon": "icon2.png", "visibility": true }
  },
  {
    "name": { "text": "Mike", "icon": "icon3.png", "visibility": true },
    "surname": { "text": "Jobs", "icon": "icon5.png", "visibility": false }
  }
]`;

const deserialized: any = JSON.parse(json);

let validatedArray: User[];

if (validateUserArray(deserialized)) {
  // here deserialized is a User[], not an any.
  validatedArray = deserialized;
}
```

Comment: It seems work but it is very complicated to maintain the code, is there any other way more maintainable?

Comment: If your types are "regular" (i.e. the user interface has 20 fields, all of them of type Field), you could make User a class, instantiate a prototype with `const proto = new User()` and use Object.keys(proto) to get a list of the fields to be checked, via `return obj != null && Object.keys(proto).every(fieldName => isField(obj[fieldName]))` in isUser.

Comment: Or, use `io-ts`. More maintainable, for sure, but maybe not so simple. You could also build a code generator, to build you `isUser` function, and run it every time the User interface changes.

Comment: I Added a `isUserDynamic` function, alternative to `isUser` to show how it could be done, keeping `User` as an interface.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems work but it is very complicated to maintain the code, is there any other way more maintainable?

Yes, you can let [typia](https://typia.io/) generate the function. Given the following typescript input:

```js
import typia from "typia";

export interface User {
    name: Field;
    surname: Field;
};
export type Field = { icon: string; text: string; visibility: boolean };

const IsUser = typia.createIs<User>();

const u1 = {
    name: { icon: "i", text: "t", visibility: true },
    surname: { icon: "i", text: "t", visibility: true },
};

const u2 = {
    name: { text: "t", visibility: true },
    surname: { icon: "i", text: "t", visibility: true },
};


if (IsUser(u1)) {
    console.log("u1 is User");
} else {
    console.log("u1 is not User");
}

if (IsUser(u2)) {
    console.log("u2 is User");
} else {
    console.log("u2 is not User");
}
```

The compiled javascript is

```js
import typia from "typia";
;
const IsUser = input => {
    return "object" === typeof input && null !== input && ("object" === typeof input.name && null !== input.name && ("string" === typeof input.name.icon && "string" === typeof input.name.text && "boolean" === typeof input.name.visibility) && ("object" === typeof input.surname && null !== input.surname && ("string" === typeof input.surname.icon && "string" === typeof input.surname.text && "boolean" === typeof input.surname.visibility)));
};
const u1 = {
    name: { icon: "i", text: "t", visibility: true },
    surname: { icon: "i", text: "t", visibility: true },
};
const u2 = {
    name: { text: "t", visibility: true },
    surname: { icon: "i", text: "t", visibility: true },
};
if (IsUser(u1)) {
    console.log("u1 is User");
}
else {
    console.log("u1 is not User");
}
if (IsUser(u2)) {
    console.log("u2 is User");
}
else {
    console.log("u2 is not User");
}
```

and the output is

```
u1 is User
u2 is not User
```

All the magic is in the `IsUser` function which you do not have to create yourself.